# Backing up Cassandra Cluster with snapshots and uploading to s3/vm?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

Is backing up Cassandra using snapshots and uploading them a common thing to do with a cluster?

I was thinking of having a cron job on each node take a snapshot, tar it, and upload it every 24 hours but I am a bit worried about the performance implications of it. Once the data on a node gets big couldn't this cripple it?

Answer (score 3):

The backups created by `nodetool snapshot` in Cassandra are hard links, so effectively won't use any more space than the original file. See this post for an explanation of hard / soft links:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

However, if you are not clearing the snapshots using `nodetool clearsnapshot` then your data will grow on the cluster over time. The docs here talk about [clearing snapshots](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupDeleteSnapshot.html)

Incidentally [nodetool tablestats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsTablestats.html?) (formerly `nodetool cfstats`) is very useful for seeing how much snapshot data you're using on a given node for a given table.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 kind of backup strategies, full backup and incremental backups. Once you take a full backup enable incremental backups on each node. you can make 1 cron job to sync all incremental backups to s3. (Fullbackup + all incremental backups after this makes a uptodate backup).

So you can have another cron job which you might run only weekend or once in a month to remove all previous backups and take a full backup.